# Сокращение слова "между"

Tags: орфография, сокращения

Каково правильное сокращение слова "между" — **м/у** или **м/ду**?

Comment: Нет у слова "между" правильного сокращения, оно вообще не сокращается.

Comment: Приведите контекст: между одинаковыми ли сущностями, две их или более и т. п.

Answer (score 1):

Большой толковый словарь:
[**МЕЖ, предлог**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6&all=x&help=1), *кого-чего, кем-чем. **Разг.*** = Между.
Пропустить меж пальцев. Пройти меж столбов. Пролегать меж двух озер. *Меж ими всё рождало споры* (Пушкин). **Меж тем, *в зн. нареч.*** В то время, тем временем. Меж тем прошло два года. **Меж тем как; меж тем, как, *в зн. союза*** (*при сопоставлении двух явлений, происходящих одновременно*). В то время как, между тем как. **Меж нами говоря, *в зн. вводн. словосоч.*** Говоря по секрету.

Единственная возможность для грамотного сокращения — использование предлога **меж**.
Но — такое употребление возможно только в разговорной речи или при использовании устойчивых словосочетаний (например, *меж двух огней*).
Никакие "м/у" или "м/ду" правилами не предусмотрены.

Comment: Слово "_меж_", пожалуй, уже можно смело отнести к устаревшим, и даже в устоявшихся оборотах (_меж двух огней_) оно чаще заменяется на "_между_".

Comment: Это _слишком_ смело. Посмотрите, сколько результатов находится гуглом в современных книгах напр. для "меж-сестёр".

Comment: @Alex_ander, соглашусь с вами. Но всё же есть тенденция постепенного замещения "меж" на "между".